# ActiveJDBC instrumentation with Eclipse debug

Tags: eclipse, gradle, activejdbc

I am using ActiveJDBC and I am able to get the instrumentation generated properly and included when I build and run my project with gradle from the command line.

When I use Debug As/ Run As from Eclipse, the instrumentation seems to be skipped and I get errors when I try to query using ActiveJDBC. Because of this I am unable to get a properly running application where I can set breakpoints for debugging.

I am using Spring with springboot for the project.

Comment: were you able to make this work?

Comment: I gave up on active JDBC and stuck with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

This page provides information on running instrumentation from Eclipse http://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration

Please, follow the steps. If you are not using Maven, you can create a simple script, and call that as a builder from Eclipse.

Comment: I am unable to get this to work. This is the only thing that is stopping me from using activejdbc. I'm update more info on the original question - hope you can help me in finding a solution.

Comment: I've tried the steps you've linked for standalone, but that too seems to be behaving incorrectly. I've been able to get the instrumentation script to run before a launch but somehow the instrumented classes are not being picked up.
The order of builders for my project is Java Builder, Gradle Builder and then the Instrumentation script. Is there something that I am doing wrong?